# c# memcached: Is it better to store large objects i.e. big objects OR several small objects as value in key value pairs?

Tags: c#, memcached

We have API with certain blacklisted IP addresses. We don't want to let users of these IP address access this API. We want to save these Blocked IPs in Memcache. We have following choices:

1. Keep one key blockedIPs that would return blacklist of all blocked IPs . When we get request from any IP, We fetch all these IPs and check if current IP matches with any of these, then return back unauthorized status OR
2. Keep multiple keys i.e. blockedIP_{IpAddress} for each blocked IP address. When we get a request from any IP i.e.161.42.32.98, we check if blockedIP_161.42.32.98 exists? If it does, we return back unauthorized status.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer.  If the blocklist is changing very rapidly then you want #2 so that you aren't invalidating an entire large entry on a constant basis.

However, if the blocklist changes only every few hours and is not huge then #1 is the better bet because you don't have to listen to all global cache changes.

Comment: I understand benefits of #2 i.e. not invalidating large entry and less payload in cache response. I don't understand what you mean by "because you don't have to listen to all global cache changes."

Comment: @sahil - how will you (or memcached) know when a new blocked IP has been added or removed in scenario #2 unless you are monitoring the entire cache for all its key changes?

Comment: but we just need to check if cache has particular blocked ip or not, do we really need to monitor entire blocked ip cache?

Comment: @sahil - If memcached is worth having at all it is caching data locally on clients that use it frequently and keeping it up to date.  If that is not the case then you need to use method #2 for sure and just pay for the network hop every time (but at least keep it small).